# how to debug a faulty power button?

Tags: button

I've got an android tablet which can't be turn on anymore: Pushing the power button does nothing, screen stays black.

I've checked the battery with the multimeter which gives me a reading and there's the LED indicating a correct charge. So I suspect the problem is with the power button itself.

[image]

[image]

There is no problem of continuity between the PWR on the board and the PWR on the little circuit.

How can I check where the problem is now for this power button which seems faulty?

Comment: VTC - Questions concerning the repair of consumer electronics devices are off topic here.

Comment: The question is HOW the button works in an electronic device like a tablet. Obviously the question happens more when the device is faulty. I didn't ask for repairing this device, only on this particular point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test if the button works use your multimeter in continuity test mode( or resistance mode if you don't have continuity test mode) and measure the two pins of the button. When you press the button you have to hear the beep in continuity mode (or see 0 ohms in resistence mode). If you don't see this the button is broken and you have to replace it.

Another test you can do is short circuit the PWR and GND pads briefly, that's what the button do to power the device. If the device don't start doing this, then the problem is not the button, is elsewhere.

Comment: Don't test continuity/resistance with the button still connected to the tablet - the voltage will confuse your meter. Instead, check for voltage across the button that disappears when pressed. The short out test also works.